# Is there a way to change formcontrolname (but keep same name) in a form?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a reactive form in Angular6 where a formcontrolname change when a value in a mat-select is chosen but it sends me an ExpressionChangedError.

I've tried something which works but I get an error in the console.

```
<input
  *ngIf="variableForm.get('type').value === 'var3'"
  matInput
  type="number"
  placeholder="Value of variable"
  id="value"
  formControlName="value">

<mat-select
  *ngIf="variableForm.get('type').value === 'var4'"
  placeholder="Value of variable"
  id="value"
  formControlName="value">
  <mat-option [value]="true">True</mat-option>
  <mat-option [value]="false">False</mat-option>
</mat-select>

<mat-error *ngIf="isDirty('value')">
  <div *ngIf="required('value')">
    Value required
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="variableForm.get('value').hasError('pattern')">
    Value must be a number
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="variableForm.get('value').hasError('invalidString')">
    Value cannot contain special characters
  </div>
</mat-error>
```

Actually, I have an ExpressionChangedError in console when I switch between some select 'type' value (var1, var2, var3 or var4)

Comment: Hi there, please try to make a minimal repro on stackblitz that'd help people to try live and then get back to you if someone finds anything

Comment: Okay I'll do that ;)